Jira Plugin - how to include Gson
I'm trying to include gson in a jira plugin. However, I keep getting ClassDefNotFound...
What I tried:

Inlcude the maven plugin in compile scope
Include the maven plugin provided scope
Add to Import-Package com.google.gson.*;version="0",
Add to Import-Package com.google.gson.*,
Trying an older version of gson that matches one of the versions that comes with provided dependencies..

None it works.. Any help?
